# Column wise searching in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I need a form which will take d input like text, radio buttons, checkboxes, select options etc. How do I use the data entered in the form to display only those records which match the data entered in the form? I need to display the matching records below the search form.

This is is my search.ctp

```
`<? $this->Form->input('name',`
`['label' => 'First name',`
`'type' => 'text',`    
`]`
`); ?>` 
`<? $this->Form->input('english',`
`['label' => 'English Language',`
`'type' => 'checkbox',`    
`]`
`); ?>`
```

And this is my controller

```
`$fname = $this->request->data['name'];`
`$eng = $this->request->data['english'];`
`$student = $this->Students->find('all', array`
`("conditions" => array (` 
`'AND' => array (`
`array('name LIKE' => "%$fname%")` 
`array('english' =>$eng)`
`),`    

`)));`
`$this->set("Students",$student);`
```

When I enter a name it displays the record but when I select the checkbox it doesn't display any records.

Comment: You would presumably start with something like `$results = $table->find();` and then add conditions with a series of `$results->andWhere(...)` with the ... filled in based on the data you get from your form. Impossible to give any better help than that with the minimal info you have provided. Show us the code you've written to solve this problem, and explain the problems you're having with it, and maybe we can help more then. See the help on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it does not matches SO standards. You can improve your question. Meanwhile you can take a look at this plugin https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search